# Is there a command which will force Linux to flush cache of one file on an NFS share?

Tags: nfs, cache

Related to [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7575140/75801), I am wondering if there is a way for me to flush the NFS cache / force Linux to see the most up-to-date copy of a file that's on an NFS share.

I have a situation where four Apache servers mount the same directory via NFS, and when one server make a change to a file, it takes about 5 - 10 seconds for the other servers to see that change. If a second change is made to that file within this window, it may overwrite the first change.

The `fstab` entry for the filesystem is:

```
172.16.1.15:/home               /media/home     nfs     vers=3,defaults,noauto,sync,acregmin=1          0       0
```

Is there a command which will force Linux to flush cache of one file on an NFS share?

Comment: What apache caching mechanism you using?

Comment: @usermane: I'm not using an Apache caching mechanism. The files in question are PHP files, and when they're modified on one host, the other hosts don't see that change for a few seconds.

Answer (score 13):

Check these items, and see if any work for you:

1. **On the client**, if you're not already using the `cto` option in the *options* column of the `/etc/fstab` line for your NFS filesystem, add it.  `cto` tells the nfs client to open files via close-to-open, which makes them refresh the file whenever they open it.
2. **On the server**, make sure your filesystem is exported with the `sync` option, and not `async`.  With synchronous writes, the client will flush to disk when the file is closed. (*or with nfs V3, whenever a commit() is made*).  There may be a performance hit that way, but if you're doing writes to an NFS filesystem, you definitely want `sync` set.
3. Following on the heels of that stackoverflow post, opening file with O_DIRECT works only if the kernel was compiled with CONFIG_NFS_DIRECTIO.
4. Also, make sure you have the following settings in your httpd.conf file:

   - `EnableMMAP off`
   - `EnableSendfile off`

   From the apache performance tuning documentation:

   - If you memory-map a file located on an NFS-mounted filesystem and a process on another NFS client machine deletes or truncates the file, your process may get a bus error the next time it tries to access the mapped file content.
   - Turning off EnableSendfile won't specifically help with the sync/async behavior of NFS, but it needs to be turned off if you're using apache with NFS.

Comment: Thanks! These are great suggestions. I am not using `cto` on the client and I will try that. I don't have either `sync` nor `async` on the server; I just added `sync`. `O_DIRECT` didn't help me because it's actually PHP that's reading these files and it can't open them with `O_DIRECT` in any way I can find.

Comment: @Josh, did it solve your problem? We are blocked on the same issue! Could you please update this post?

Answer (score 4):

Within a given process, calling opendir and closedir on the parent directory of a file invalidates the NFS cache.   I used this while programming a job scheduler.  Very, very helpful.   Try it!

Answer (score -1):

If you open the given file in a non-cached program (like vim or emacs) and then close, it will update/clear the cache for that file

Comment: What is your definition of "non-cached program", and do you have a reference for that statement?